# Why is package not updated by composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have installed a Laravel application together with the admin menu [voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager).

I wanted to update to new newest voyager version. The current version on GitHub is 1.0.11 and inside of `composer.json` I have

```
 "require": {
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.0"
```

After running `composer update` I noticed that there has been no update for the `tcg/voyager` package:

[image]

In the `composer.lock` file I found

```
"name": "tcg/voyager",
            "version": "v1.0.11",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager.git",
                "reference": "919fcbb5c9a53d601b4b5eeb983e2a29a488e1cb"
            },
```

so everything looks like I have the newest version of the `tcg/voyager` package.

However, I clearly see that the [MenuItemPolicy.php](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.0/src/Policies/MenuItemPolicy.php) file differs from my local version. The latest change that has been committed 12 hours ago has not taken place in my local version. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There hasn't been a tag created since that commit, so your `^1.0` version constraint won't find it. If you want to use the head of the **1.0** branch, you can use something like `1.0.x@dev`, but be aware that you will potentially pull in changes not considered stable by the package author.

Comment: So I replace `^1.0` exactly by `1.0.x@dev` in the `composer.json` file and run composer update?

Comment: @Adam Yep, I think that should do it

Comment: ....but even if this works, better ask yourself why you don't want to use properly released versions. If you don't have that package under your own control, you might get screwed up if the maintainer messes up with his master branch